# Sharepoint - How to remove unused columns

Tags: sharepoint, attributes, content-type, sharepoint-online

I have created a document library with site content types. On the library site (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF0nm.jpg) this is what I want to show, cost and project manager. On the document sets site (after I click on the document which brings me to another page) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmvUZ.jpg). How can I remove the empty columns cost and project manager? Please advise.

I've tried to remove this from the child site but, it removed from the document site as well. I tried to hide it in the child site and it also hide it from the library site.

Comment: You could create a new view where these fields are hidden, and set the web part to use this view instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharepoint How to remove unused columns in child site of document set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504686/sharepoint-how-to-remove-unused-columns-in-child-site-of-document-set)

Comment: Hi @rlv-dan, how do you create a view inside of the document sets? I am able to create 1 in the document library, however, it does not bring the view into the document sets. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code into a script editor web part in the docsethomepage.aspx(document set home page) page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("table.ms-listviewtable>thead th:contains('Project Cost')").hide();
    $("table.ms-listviewtable>thead th:contains('Project Manager')").hide();
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT, is there another method in doing this? Just curious.

Comment: There is not a OOTB method to achieve it, we have to use custom code to achieve it. In the OOTB, we can unselect the column in list view, unfortunately, it will affect the parent view.